# Type Error: findByID is not a function (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two separate Folders.

/controller/anbieter.js

```
function getAnbieterById(req, res) {
        var userid = parseInt(req.params.id);
        let anbieter = Anbieter.findById(userid);
        res.send(anbieter);
    };
```

/model/anbieter.js

```
findById(id){
        let sql = `SELECT * FROM Anbieter WHERE Anbieter_id= ${id};`;
    
        db.query(sql);
    }
```

I am getting error that Anbieter.findById is not a function

Comment: you need to export and import "findById" properly. show us your export and import sections

Comment: yes i have import this: const Anbieter = require("../model/anbieter");

Comment: And how you are exporting findById  in ../model/anbieter?

Comment: Assuming `Anbieter` is a class - you need to construct it first with the `new` keyword.

Comment: but it is not a class and you are not adding new anywhere.
Use module.exports to export the function from anbieter

Comment: `var db = require('../config/db');

class Anbieter {
    constructor(vorname, nachname, Automodelle_Automodell_id){
        this.vorname = vorname;
        this.nachname = nachname;
        this.Automodelle_Automodell_id = Automodelle_Automodell_id;
    }

    findById(id){
        let sql = `SELECT * FROM Anbieter WHERE Anbieter_id= ${id};`;
    
        db.query(sql);
    }
}

module.exports = Anbieter;` this is complete code

Comment: This looks fine. 
But why do you need a class? just create a function and exporting that function could solve your problem rt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are calling `Anbieter.findById(userid);` is supposed to be defined as a static method. so instead of `findById` use

```js
 class Anbieter{
  static findById(){
   // your logic goes here
  }
}
```

And, I think you would like to use `async` with your functions since db queries are asynchronous.

Comment: i get this TypeError: Anbieter.findById is not a constructor

Comment: Are you importing the Anbieter class in your code?

Comment: i post the complete code in upper comment. Yes i importing the class in controller/anbieter.js

Answer (score 0):

export function findById and import in this function /controller/anbieter.js .

Comment: can you explain this with example code please?

Comment: `const Anbieter = require("../model/anbieter");    module.exports = {
    getAnbieterById
}

function getAnbieterById(req, res) {
    var userid = parseInt(req.params.id);
    let anbieter = Anbieter.findById(userid);
    res.send(anbieter);
};` my code looks like this